# calendar component display not complete

Tags: angular, primeng

I have a weird issue, my calendar display is not complete, like this image, you can see the bottom part is missing:
[image]

However, when I trying to open google chrome developer tool to take a look, it shows up the entire calendar show up, like this picture.

[image]

Here is my code:

```
                <p-calendar styleClass="schedulerCalendar" appendTo="body" [disabled]="disableEdit" [(ngModel)]="start_time" [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}"
                    [showTime]="true" [monthNavigator]="true" [yearNavigator]="true" yearRange="{{yearRange}}" placeholder="{{ 'Select date and time' | i18next }}"
                    [minDate]="minDate" showButtonBar="true" readonlyInput="true" (onSelect)="setStartTime($event)"
                    (onFocus)="onCalendarStartOpen()" [stepMinute]="NEAREST_MINUTE" (onClearClick)="clearStartTime()"
                    [showIcon]="true" [baseZIndex]="100000" [showTransitionOptions]="" [hideTransitionOptions]="">
                </p-calendar>
```

here is my css class

```
.schedulerCalendar {
    &.p-calendar {
        .p-datepicker {
            th {
                text-align: center;
            }
            box-shadow: 0 2px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
            border-radius: 1rem;
        }
        .p-inputtext {
            border-radius: 0;
            border: 0;
            border-bottom: 1px solid $GS10;
            font-size: 1.4rem;
            padding: 0;
            color: $GS10;
            box-shadow: none;
            &:focus {
                box-shadow: none;
            }
        }
        .p-datepicker-trigger {
            border-radius: 0;
            background: none;
            border: none;
            border-bottom: 1px solid $GS10;
            color: $GS10;
            box-shadow: none;
            .pi-calendar {
                font-size: 1.4rem;
            }
        }
        width: 50%;
    }
}
```

Comment: try to set overflow auto to calendar parent

Comment: it looks like a styling issue. can you paste the content of schedulerCalendar class? it would also help if you can paste the full content of the HTML with the styling

Comment: @DEV_404_NF

Hi I added the content of schedulerCalendar class.

Comment: try to set appendTo= "the parent div instead of the body"